# Select Records if the Date is Equal to Selected Date on Select in HTML

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Currently, I am upgrading a Simple Web Application of Employee Management. The ADMIN told me to show the Employee on the list Before they resigned, then hide it if the Date today is greater than the resigned date of an Employee.

Also, the newly hired Employee will be shown on the list if the Selected Month is The Month they were Hired. If not then it will not be shown.

eg.: I am hired March 19, 2018.

Then I Must Be shown in the list in March 2018, If the Selected date is February or Past Then I will be Hidden on the List.

I have a code that will only show on the list is the Regular Employee and Probation, It means that the Resigned Employee is not listed.

```
                BEGIN
                    SELECT  empID, badgenum, first_name, ISNULL(c.groupShortName,'') groupName, 
                    ISNULL(b.statDesc, '') statDesc,  ISNULL(email,'') email, ISNULL(contact_no,'') contact_no
                    FROM userinfo a
                    LEFT JOIN tblEmpStatus b on a.employment_status = b.statID
                    LEFT JOIN tblGroup c on a.groupNo = c.groupID
                where a.employment_status IS NOT NULL OR MONTH(a.resigned_date) <= CAST(@date AS VARCHAR) AND a.employment_status IN (0,1)
                ORDER BY first_name ASC 
                END
```

This Code is for Displaying only the Active Employees on the Table.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think you error is in here: `(a.employment_status <> 2 or a.employment_status <> null)`. It should be: `(a.employment_status IS NOT NULL AND a.employment_status <> 2) `.

Comment: Thanks, sir for Updating my Code. But the main problem is the example Above. Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using SQL 2014 Sir.

Comment: Second error: `MONTH(a.resigned_date) <= CAST(@date AS VARCHAR)` - you are comparing a number (MONTH) against a string containing a full date value.

Comment: Because I have a `SELECT ELEMENT` in my Html Sir. Example: ` <option value="1">January</option>` So the Value of Month is 1. and Searching in Database that was equals to Month 1.